# Hardware issues running Linux from USB

Tags: usb, operating-systems

I'm aware there are potential drawbacks when running Linux off a USB drive such as SATA bus/USB speed differences and the finite lifespan of flash drives, but all this aside, are there any potential issues with hardware compatibility? For instance, not recognizing all the processors or being unable to connect to the wireless controller.

Perhaps this is too general a question and the answer depends on the underlying hardware, but even if that was the case, it would be good to know. It would be a beautiful thing if I could reasonably expect things to work regardless of the computer being used.

Comment: Let's assume we're always using an x-bit OS on an x-bit processor.

Comment: There can always be a potential issue of incompatibility with any OS and hardware combo due to lack of drivers. As such this is too broad. If you have a specific issue then you can ask about how to solve it. Attempting to predict whether your LiveOS will be compatible with every possible system configuration is pointless.

Comment: Fair enough. It'll certainly be a Linux distro on the USB (thus the edit). It already seems as though wireless will not work on Apple products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the PC's BIOS supports booting from USB, you shouldn't see any difference in hardware recognition between running that way and running the same distro from a hard drive.

However, that isn't really the kind of issue you *will* see. The issues you are likely to get are to do with pen drive reliability. It is important to remember that pen drives and SD cards are not the same as an SSD. They are designed to be cheap and have relatively low reliability.

An external SSD would be better. Though of course, it is rather more expensive!

Comment: Appreciate the response but I think this may not quite be the case, as some early tests with a Macbook failed to connect to the wireless controller despite everything else operating as normal.

Comment: As for reliability, I'm counting on the stick's lifetime warranty and frequent backups (which, granted, will only further decrease the drive's lifespan ;)

Comment: Re your Macbook test, did you try the same live cd from some other bootable media? The point is that the result will almost certainly be the same. It is the live distro that is likely having the issue not the fact that it is running from USB.

Comment: Ahh good point, I should give that a go. But who has writable DVDs these days. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Ha ha, true. They are an increasingly rare breed. Bit like floppy discs before them they are dying out. I have a USB one somewhere.